# In my Android Studio i do not see plugin bloc code generator

Tags: android, android-studio

In my Android Studio, I can not see plugin bloc code generator

Below is the screenshot.

[image: AndroidStudio]

Comment: Do you mean this? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12129-bloc/versions In that case it's just called bloc

Comment: They change name ? i see on video there is on plug called Bloc Code Generator , let me make screenshot how look

Comment: There is lots of ways to generate bloc code, the plugin that I linked is one of them, you can also use live templates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the plugin that I have linked (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12129-bloc/versions) and they did change the name apparently. You can see from your screenshot that version 1.60 was released in September 27th 2019. The same release date and version can be found in the plugin that I linked. I hope this answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

Just type **flutter bloc** and you should see **Bloc** Plugin in Android Studio